# Parec to create an Audio Stream

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

I am trying to use the parec to record the audio that is playing from the computer (not the microphone). I am currently using the command `parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_05.0.analogtereo.monitor --file-format=wav output.wav`

I would like to record as a stream, so that I can playback while recording. However the command in its current state does not do that. While recording, I see that the file `output.wav` is getting bigger, but when trying to play it `aplay output.wav` it instantly finishes with no output. I have looked through the man pages, but can't seem to find anything there.

tl;dr **How can I record an audio stream using parec?**

Answer (score 3):

I managed to record my computer's audio using:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor --file-format=wav test.wav
```

You were probably using the wrong source. You can find the right one using `pactl list sources`.

Comment: One could also use the number associated with the device name. For example: `parec -d 1 --file-format=wav /tmp/test.wav`.